# MongoDB - How to extract field with max value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDb collection `genre_count` as

```
user | genre         | count
-----+---------------+-------
1    | Western       | 2
1    | Adventure     | 1
1    | Comedy        | 5
2    | Western       | 3
2    | Thriller      | 1
2    | Romance       | 2
```

I need to extract the genre for each user with maximum count i.e. for user 1 , the genre with maximum count is **Comedy** with **Count** 5. I tried using couple of ways as:

```
db.genre_count.aggregate([
  {
  $group:{
     _id:{

        user:"$user",
        genre:"$genre"
     },
     max_val:{
         $max: "$count"
     }
   }
 }
])
```

I thought this would work but it returned the count of the user for each genre so basically it returned me all the records.

Then I tried another solution which worked partially in :

```
db.genre_count.aggregate([
  {
  $group:{
     _id:{

        user:"$user"
     },
     max_val:{
         $max: "$count"
     }
   }
 }
])
```

But this only returned the maximum value as it has no corresponding genre information for that maximum value. Is there any way I can get the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return the maximum count and genre list, you need to use the `$max` in your group stage to return the maximum "Count" for each group then use `$push` accumulator operator to return a list of "Genre Name" and "Count" for each group.

From there you need to use the `$map` operator in your `$project` stage to return a list of genre_names alongside the maximum count. The `$cond` here is used to compare each genre count to the maximum value.

```
db.genre_count.aggregate([
        { '$group': {
            '_id': '$user', 
            'maxCount': { '$max': '$count' }, 
            'genres': { 
                '$push': {
                    'name': '$genre', 
                    'count': '$count' 
                }
            }
        }}, 
        { '$project': { 
            'maxCount': 1, 
            'genres': { 
                '$setDifference': [
                    { '$map': {
                        'input': '$genres', 
                        'as': 'genre', 
                        'in': {
                            '$cond': [
                                { '$eq': [ '$$genre.count', '$maxCount' ] }, 
                                '$$genre.name', 
                                false
                            ]
                        }
                    }}, 
                    [false]
                ]
            }
        }}
    ])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this aggregate:

```
db.genre_count.aggregate([
{
    $sort: {user:1, count:1}
},
{
    $group: 
    { 
        _id: "$user", 
        maxCount: {$max: "$count"}, 
        genre: {$last: "$genre"} 
    }
}])
```

Comment: it is working and is good for me to get going but i have a question. Is there anyway i could extract all the values with the same max count i.e. if multiple genres have same max count, it is only returning one

Comment: @scrpaingnoob I have tries to answer the second question of yours. In the current answer, the assumption is that after sorting you pick the last genre(which holds the max value) and you get all the corresponding values. I have tried to explain the approach as well.